# latex - attachfile does not show the file

Tags: file, pdf, latex, attachment, tex

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or I didn't get what the command/package does. I was expecting to create a "pin" that once clicked, opens the document (an image in this sample case but I eed for an excel file)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}
 \attachfile{avatar.bmp}
\end{document}
```

With this, I got the pin. But when I click it, nothing happens. Where am I wrong?

EDIT

The size of the .pdf file is too small for having the image as an attachment (24kb the pdf file while around 400kb the image). So I guess it's not attached properly. how can I get it?

Comment: Hi! Is the bmp file with such name in the same folder as the tex file?? For reference: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile

Comment: yes, it is! it's in the same folder. I read the documentation and I didn't find anything strange or missing... I really dunno. besides, I'm using Unix but in the Mac, I cannot even see the pin unless I don't use `\noattachfile` command

Comment: @Stefano I am curious, did you solve this in some way?  Does what I posted below help?  I've heard of a similar problem and it'd be good to know what to recommend to them.

Comment: actually no. it doesn't work. I tried different ways but nothing seems to work...

Comment: @Stefano  Oh, I'm sorry. I'll remove this answer then, so that it doesn't mislead someone else. (If you ever want it restored for some reason let me know.)  I will look more into it, and if I run into a solution I'll come back and repost. Thank you for feedback.

Comment: @Stefano: I can't replicate the problem. When I use your example code with the file `example-image.jpg`, I get a pin that I can *double-click* in Adobe Reader to open the file.

Comment: @Werner: I dunno. maybe it's only a Mac version issue

Comment: It does happen sometimes as well to me on win10. I am not sure, but it could be that recompiling multiple times helps